# Windows 8 Application Timeout

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Anyone know if there is a way to disable a Windows Metro app from timing out.  I'm looking for something similar to IdelDetectionMOde in WP7?  I have an application that needs to constantly stay up until the user dismisses or closes it.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to prevent an app from being suspended when the user switches away?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to make sure that Surface never picks up the user as idle and shuts off the screen.  WP7 phones do this after XX seconds of inactivity, however, you can override the timeout by setting the IdleDetectionMode to none.  I understand that this negatively affects battery life, however, this app is designed to be used when the Surface is plugged in.